# ajax request not displaying the response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, nginx

I have a nodejs application which is sending the response with header as `application/json`. The client is making a `http` ajax request and getting the 200 OK status. I am also able to view the json response from the Rest Client.

But I am not seeing any response on the UI. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Firebug console on my Firefox:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:30
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 15 Jun 2016 12:13:34 GMT
ETag:W/"1e-p2J1WXSidVD0/pV2ACqLcQ"
X-Powered-By:Express
Request Headers
view source
```

Node js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/button', function (req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('{"name":"<input type=button>"}');
  res.end("response sent");
})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

On the client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginDemo.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">
    <div id="loginForm">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

On script side:

```
$.get("http://172.28.88.28:8081/button",
function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
}, function(err){
    alert('error > '+err);
});
```

Comment: Add an error handler on the clientside and see if it is triggered

Comment: Added error handler and not even going to the error block.

Comment: So how is the Ajax call being triggered in the clientside?

Comment: @epascarello:  Updated the html code which call the jquery code in the question.

Comment: You are including the script before you are including jQuery? So the Ajax call is called onload?

Comment: @epascarello No Luck even after doing that. I am getting 200 OK message in the response though. Also I am running the html code from the apache server to avoid the cors origin errors

Comment: If you use console.log instead of alert, does it make a difference?

Comment: "Also I am running the html code from the apache server to avoid the cors origin errors" — You're loading the HTML from an Apache server and making a request with Ajax to a NodeJS server, which is a **different server** and you expect that to **prevent** same origin errors? That will **cause** same origin errors, not the reverse.

Comment: "Firebug console on my Firefox" — That looks like the Network tab, not the Console. What does the Console say?

Answer (score 0):

Same-origin policy -- I believe is your problem ... I see in your code you are using port 8081 is your request coming from the same domain wiht the same protocol and on the same port(8081) ? ...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy
If you don't add code to display the errors on your ajax request ... you will not
see this error in network tab ...
try this in you code:

```
// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://yourClientAddress:8081');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
```